# How to activate ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown only in debug mode?

Tags: delphi

I need to activate the `ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown` functionality to report the memory leaks of my application, but only under debug mode (when the Delphi IDE is running). How can I do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

try using the [`DebugHook`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.DebugHook) variable

```
ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown:=DebugHook<>0;
```

Comment: And probably disable the stupid warning associated with `DebugHook`,   `{$WARN SYMBOL_PLATFORM OFF}`

Comment: Stupid (for the versions of Delphi I have,) because they only work on the Windows platform, so for me, it's just noise.

Comment: I don't agree that the warning is stupid. I do realize that Kylix didn't get a follow-up and Delphi.NET got replaced by Delphi Prism. But with the things that future Delphi versions will bring (read the roadmap, demos during DelphiLive last year, and events this year some of which had x64 and/or Mac compiler previews), I think the warning can be annoying but is not stupid.

Comment: @jason Well switch the warning off then and stop whining! Just because you don't need it doesn't mean many others want it. What's more the good folk at Emba gave you control of the warning. Good job in my view.

Comment: @jasonpenny, only disable warnings as a last resort. Its always better to correct the problem first.

Comment: Is there a global way to turn it off? I see it in the project options, but not global options.  (I would change the word stupid in my comment, but there's no edit link showing for that one...)

Comment: the project options are global. How much more global could it get?

Comment: The project options are project specific (hence the name). There are still global options in the IDE valid for every project - they are just not the same options available. Although there is also something like default project options.

Answer (score 27):

If you mean "debug mode" as compiled using the Debug build configuration (D2007+), you'll have the DEBUG symbol defined, so you can activate the ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown even when running oustide the debugger with:

```
{$IFDEF DEBUG}
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;
{$ENDIF}
```

If you want to run only if the debugger is present, look at [RRUZ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317384/how-activate-reportmemoryleaksonshutdown-only-in-debug-mode/5317396#5317396)

Answer (score 4):

I usually use the **IsDebuggerPresent** API function and also surround it with a DEBUG symbol check so the code doesn't end up in release builds:

```
{$IFDEF DEBUG}   
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutDown := IsDebuggerPresent();
{$ENDIF}
```

The function should already be declared in the Windows unit, if you're not using an ancient version of Delphi and works on Windows 2000 and newer.

Comment: IsDebuggerPresent is not declared in the Windows unit, so:
`function IsDebuggerPresent: LongBool; stdcall;`
`function IsDebuggerPresent; external kernel32 name 'IsDebuggerPresent';`